# Reading/Editing XLIFF using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I need to parse an [XLIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) file using C#, but I'm having some trouble. These files are fairly complex, containing a huge amount of nodes.

Basically, all I need to do is read the **source** node from each **trans-unit** node, do some processing on it, and insert the processed text into the corresponding **target** node (which will always be present, but empty).

An example of one of the nodes I need to parse would be (the whole file may contain 100s of these):

```
<trans-unit id="0000000002" datatype="text" restype="string">
<source>Windows Update is not installed</source>
<target/>
<iws:segment-metadata tm_score="0.00" ws_word_count="6" max_segment_length="0">
<iws:status target_content="placeholders_only"/>
</iws:segment-metadata>
<iws:boundary-seg sequence="bs20721"/>
<iws:markup-seg sequence="0000000001">
</trans-unit>
```

The **trans-unit** nodes can be buried deep in the files, the header section contains a lot of data. I'd like to use LINQ to XML to read the data, but I'm not having any luck getting it to work. Here's my current code (just trying to read and output the source nodes from the file:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

        Console.WriteLine("Before loop");

        foreach (var transUnitNode in doc.Descendants("trans-unit"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In loop");
            XElement sourceNode = transUnitNode.Element("source");
            XElement targetNode = transUnitNode.Element("target");
            Console.WriteLine("Source: " + sourceNode.Value);
        }
```

I never see 'In loop' and I don't know why, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or suggest a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
XNamespace df = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
foreach (XElement transUnitNode in doc.Descendants(df + "trans-unit"))
{
  XElement sourceNode = transUnitNode.Element(df + "source");
  // and so one, use the df namespace object to qualify any elements names
}
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx.

Comment: One question - do you know if I can disable XML validation when using XDocument - I get some weird errors if the XLIFF is not valid XML (I don't care that it is, I just want to parse the data).

Comment: For example - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

Comment: XML has strict syntax rules the parser always checks, the "well-formedness rules". Validation is something different, it checks whether a documents matches a grammar in the form of a DTD or schema. Validation is not happening by default. The error you get is a well-formedness violation as the character with code 0x00 is not allowed in XML. You can't disable such checks.